# Limited variable linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

I meet a problem when working on very large scale of linear programming (approximately 10.000 variables). I use some tool such as: Lingo,MPL and CPLEX but the limited variable ups to only 1000 for free version. I know extended version is very expensive. Is there any way to solve this problem?
thank all!

Comment: Most commercial solvers (CPLEX, Gurobi, MOSEK) have no more limits on size. The limitation I guess comes from Lingo. Just change environment: use another modeling framework, or dump models to a file and call your preferred solver.

Comment: thanks! I mention a software(CPLEX studio) in stead of a solver option.

Comment: By the way, 10,000 variables is not considered "very large" anymore. We are able to solve LP problems with millions of variables in less than an hour. Although, the size alone usually doesn't determine the solution time - sparsity and numerical difficulty are two other important factors.